# Linux: How to get TCP socket options given socket descriptor?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

On Linux, Given a socket descriptor for a connected TCP socket, is there a way to obtain the TCP options for the TCP connection, like maximum segment size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch [various info](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) with [getsockopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html)() (and a couple with ioctl()), in particular the TCP_INFO socket option.

e.g.

```
struct tcp_info info;

if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, &info, sizeof info) != 0) {
   perror("getsockopt failed\n");
   return;
}
```

the maximum segment size is contained in `info.tcpi_snd_mss` and `info.tcpi_rcv_mss`, see `/usr/include/linux/tcp.h` for the content of `struct tcp_info` as the manpage says.

Comment: Aren't you missing `SOL_TCP` in there?